# Using PHP how can I convert this string variable into another form?

Tags: php

I have a huge list of `city, country` that I want to display them in a compact form of the country.

So for example I have the following **variable**

```
Hallands, Sweden
```

but how can I show it like here meaning after the `, and space` keep the two letters and capitalize.

```
Hallands, SW ?
```

Comment: Why did you remove your previous question? Did you look at `str_replace`?

Comment: did u need first two letters after" , "

Comment: How is each line in the list ended/separated?

Comment: Not all countries use the first two characters for their short version. You'd need a list of all countries and their short-hand and then replace the one with the other.

Comment: @Erik I know but nevermind, it is ok for this stage

Comment: then use strtoupper(substr($country_name, 0, 2));

Comment: Also, I would probably use [ISO 3166-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1#Current_codes) for this.

Comment: @sasikanth the variable is Hallands, Sweden not only Sweden

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ they are variables `Hallands, Sweden`

Comment: You can use a `preg_replace_callback` for this easily, but: are you sure you want the first 2 characters capatalized rather then their [ISO-3166-1 Alpha2 code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1)? They're not always the same, and people tend to recognize those abbreviations / codes better..

Comment: Hm, it you have the stuff in an array, `explode(',  ',$list); $country = mb_strtoupper(substring($list[1],0,2));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then try this

```
$str='Hallands, Sweden';

$str=explode(',',str);
 echo $str[0].','.strtoupper(substr($str[1], 0, 2));
```

Comment: there is a space so space will be zero so use 3 insted of 2 substr($str[1], 0, 3)

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
$var = explode($variable, ", ");
echo $var[0].", ".strtoupper(substr($var[1], 0, 2));
```

substr will get the first two letters and strtoupper will capitalize them.

Edit: I see you have them in one variable. I would probably explode the variable first and them apply the method above.

Comment: Hello, the variable is `Hallands, Sweden` not only `Sweden`

Comment: Sorry for that, didn't see that remark in the first place.

Comment: `strtoupper(substr(explode(",", $string)[1], 0, 2));` then?

Comment: I've added an example to my answer. It's not tested though.

Comment: The dollar sign before explode was a mistake. Just removed it. This is assuming your variable is called $variable by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
$str = "Hallands, Sweden";
$strs = explode(',', $str);

$str_country = strtoupper(substr($strs[1], 1,2));

$str = $strs[0] . ', ' . $str_country;

print_r($str);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it. 'trim' is used to remove whitespaces on either side of the word.

```
$str = "Hallands, Sweden";
$modified = array_map('trim', explode(',', $str));
$modified = $modified[0].', '.strtoupper(substr($modified[1], 0, 2));

echo $modified;
```

Answer (score 0):

These are all the steps:

- Split the string into the city and the country
- Cut the country down to two characters
- Uppercase the remaining two characters
- Paste them back together

And in code, in order:

```
// splitting
$parts = explode( ", ", $string ); // split over the comma and space
$city = $parts[0]; // city is first
$country = $parts[1]; // country is second

// shorten and uppercase
$short_country = substr( $country, 0, 2 ); // shorten to 2 chars
$short_country_uppercase = strtoupper( $short_country ); // uppercase the 2 chars

// paste back together
$new_string = $city . ", " . $short_country_uppercase;
```

This is needlessly long mostly because it'll help you understand what is happening. You can shorten it to a single line like in other answers if you want, but knowing what the code actually does helps you learn.

Answer (score 0):

You said there is a huge list, this code could help you

```
<?php

$variable_seperated_with_comma="Newyork,canada,ohio,indiana";
$countries=explode(',',$fullvariable_seperated_with_comma);
 foreach($countries as $country){
    echo strtoupper(substr($country, 0, 2));
    echo '</br>';
 }
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, people will be more familiar with the [ISO 3166-1 country codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1#Current_codes) more than a sub-string of the country name.

Here's a gist of the ISO country codes: https://gist.github.com/vxnick/380904

```
<?php

$string = 'Hallands, Sweden';
$ex = explode(",", $string); //Split the string
$countries_flip = array_flip( array_map('strtolower', getCountryCodeMap())); //Swap value and keys around (so we dont have to use array_search)

echo $ex[0] . ', ' . $countries_flip[trim(strtolower($ex[1]))]; //Output result

function getCountryCodeMap() {
//https://gist.github.com/vxnick/380904
    return array
        (
        'AF' => 'Afghanistan',
        'AX' => 'Aland Islands',
        'AL' => 'Albania',
        'DZ' => 'Algeria',
        'AS' => 'American Samoa',
        'AD' => 'Andorra',
        'AO' => 'Angola',
        'AI' => 'Anguilla',
        'AQ' => 'Antarctica',
        'AG' => 'Antigua And Barbuda',
        'AR' => 'Argentina',
        'AM' => 'Armenia',
        'AW' => 'Aruba',
        'AU' => 'Australia',
        'AT' => 'Austria',
        'AZ' => 'Azerbaijan',
        'BS' => 'Bahamas',
        'BH' => 'Bahrain',
        'BD' => 'Bangladesh',
        'BB' => 'Barbados',
        'BY' => 'Belarus',
        'BE' => 'Belgium',
        'BZ' => 'Belize',
        'BJ' => 'Benin',
        'BM' => 'Bermuda',
        'BT' => 'Bhutan',
        'BO' => 'Bolivia',
        'BA' => 'Bosnia And Herzegovina',
        'BW' => 'Botswana',
        'BV' => 'Bouvet Island',
        'BR' => 'Brazil',
        'IO' => 'British Indian Ocean Territory',
        'BN' => 'Brunei Darussalam',
        'BG' => 'Bulgaria',
        'BF' => 'Burkina Faso',
        'BI' => 'Burundi',
        'KH' => 'Cambodia',
        'CM' => 'Cameroon',
        'CA' => 'Canada',
        'CV' => 'Cape Verde',
        'KY' => 'Cayman Islands',
        'CF' => 'Central African Republic',
        'TD' => 'Chad',
        'CL' => 'Chile',
        'CN' => 'China',
        'CX' => 'Christmas Island',
        'CC' => 'Cocos (Keeling) Islands',
        'CO' => 'Colombia',
        'KM' => 'Comoros',
        'CG' => 'Congo',
        'CD' => 'Congo, Democratic Republic',
        'CK' => 'Cook Islands',
        'CR' => 'Costa Rica',
        'CI' => 'Cote D\'Ivoire',
        'HR' => 'Croatia',
        'CU' => 'Cuba',
        'CY' => 'Cyprus',
        'CZ' => 'Czech Republic',
        'DK' => 'Denmark',
        'DJ' => 'Djibouti',
        'DM' => 'Dominica',
        'DO' => 'Dominican Republic',
        'EC' => 'Ecuador',
        'EG' => 'Egypt',
        'SV' => 'El Salvador',
        'GQ' => 'Equatorial Guinea',
        'ER' => 'Eritrea',
        'EE' => 'Estonia',
        'ET' => 'Ethiopia',
        'FK' => 'Falkland Islands (Malvinas)',
        'FO' => 'Faroe Islands',
        'FJ' => 'Fiji',
        'FI' => 'Finland',
        'FR' => 'France',
        'GF' => 'French Guiana',
        'PF' => 'French Polynesia',
        'TF' => 'French Southern Territories',
        'GA' => 'Gabon',
        'GM' => 'Gambia',
        'GE' => 'Georgia',
        'DE' => 'Germany',
        'GH' => 'Ghana',
        'GI' => 'Gibraltar',
        'GR' => 'Greece',
        'GL' => 'Greenland',
        'GD' => 'Grenada',
        'GP' => 'Guadeloupe',
        'GU' => 'Guam',
        'GT' => 'Guatemala',
        'GG' => 'Guernsey',
        'GN' => 'Guinea',
        'GW' => 'Guinea-Bissau',
        'GY' => 'Guyana',
        'HT' => 'Haiti',
        'HM' => 'Heard Island & Mcdonald Islands',
        'VA' => 'Holy See (Vatican City State)',
        'HN' => 'Honduras',
        'HK' => 'Hong Kong',
        'HU' => 'Hungary',
        'IS' => 'Iceland',
        'IN' => 'India',
        'ID' => 'Indonesia',
        'IR' => 'Iran, Islamic Republic Of',
        'IQ' => 'Iraq',
        'IE' => 'Ireland',
        'IM' => 'Isle Of Man',
        'IL' => 'Israel',
        'IT' => 'Italy',
        'JM' => 'Jamaica',
        'JP' => 'Japan',
        'JE' => 'Jersey',
        'JO' => 'Jordan',
        'KZ' => 'Kazakhstan',
        'KE' => 'Kenya',
        'KI' => 'Kiribati',
        'KR' => 'Korea',
        'KW' => 'Kuwait',
        'KG' => 'Kyrgyzstan',
        'LA' => 'Lao People\'s Democratic Republic',
        'LV' => 'Latvia',
        'LB' => 'Lebanon',
        'LS' => 'Lesotho',
        'LR' => 'Liberia',
        'LY' => 'Libyan Arab Jamahiriya',
        'LI' => 'Liechtenstein',
        'LT' => 'Lithuania',
        'LU' => 'Luxembourg',
        'MO' => 'Macao',
        'MK' => 'Macedonia',
        'MG' => 'Madagascar',
        'MW' => 'Malawi',
        'MY' => 'Malaysia',
        'MV' => 'Maldives',
        'ML' => 'Mali',
        'MT' => 'Malta',
        'MH' => 'Marshall Islands',
        'MQ' => 'Martinique',
        'MR' => 'Mauritania',
        'MU' => 'Mauritius',
        'YT' => 'Mayotte',
        'MX' => 'Mexico',
        'FM' => 'Micronesia, Federated States Of',
        'MD' => 'Moldova',
        'MC' => 'Monaco',
        'MN' => 'Mongolia',
        'ME' => 'Montenegro',
        'MS' => 'Montserrat',
        'MA' => 'Morocco',
        'MZ' => 'Mozambique',
        'MM' => 'Myanmar',
        'NA' => 'Namibia',
        'NR' => 'Nauru',
        'NP' => 'Nepal',
        'NL' => 'Netherlands',
        'AN' => 'Netherlands Antilles',
        'NC' => 'New Caledonia',
        'NZ' => 'New Zealand',
        'NI' => 'Nicaragua',
        'NE' => 'Niger',
        'NG' => 'Nigeria',
        'NU' => 'Niue',
        'NF' => 'Norfolk Island',
        'MP' => 'Northern Mariana Islands',
        'NO' => 'Norway',
        'OM' => 'Oman',
        'PK' => 'Pakistan',
        'PW' => 'Palau',
        'PS' => 'Palestinian Territory, Occupied',
        'PA' => 'Panama',
        'PG' => 'Papua New Guinea',
        'PY' => 'Paraguay',
        'PE' => 'Peru',
        'PH' => 'Philippines',
        'PN' => 'Pitcairn',
        'PL' => 'Poland',
        'PT' => 'Portugal',
        'PR' => 'Puerto Rico',
        'QA' => 'Qatar',
        'RE' => 'Reunion',
        'RO' => 'Romania',
        'RU' => 'Russian Federation',
        'RW' => 'Rwanda',
        'BL' => 'Saint Barthelemy',
        'SH' => 'Saint Helena',
        'KN' => 'Saint Kitts And Nevis',
        'LC' => 'Saint Lucia',
        'MF' => 'Saint Martin',
        'PM' => 'Saint Pierre And Miquelon',
        'VC' => 'Saint Vincent And Grenadines',
        'WS' => 'Samoa',
        'SM' => 'San Marino',
        'ST' => 'Sao Tome And Principe',
        'SA' => 'Saudi Arabia',
        'SN' => 'Senegal',
        'RS' => 'Serbia',
        'SC' => 'Seychelles',
        'SL' => 'Sierra Leone',
        'SG' => 'Singapore',
        'SK' => 'Slovakia',
        'SI' => 'Slovenia',
        'SB' => 'Solomon Islands',
        'SO' => 'Somalia',
        'ZA' => 'South Africa',
        'GS' => 'South Georgia And Sandwich Isl.',
        'ES' => 'Spain',
        'LK' => 'Sri Lanka',
        'SD' => 'Sudan',
        'SR' => 'Suriname',
        'SJ' => 'Svalbard And Jan Mayen',
        'SZ' => 'Swaziland',
        'SE' => 'Sweden',
        'CH' => 'Switzerland',
        'SY' => 'Syrian Arab Republic',
        'TW' => 'Taiwan',
        'TJ' => 'Tajikistan',
        'TZ' => 'Tanzania',
        'TH' => 'Thailand',
        'TL' => 'Timor-Leste',
        'TG' => 'Togo',
        'TK' => 'Tokelau',
        'TO' => 'Tonga',
        'TT' => 'Trinidad And Tobago',
        'TN' => 'Tunisia',
        'TR' => 'Turkey',
        'TM' => 'Turkmenistan',
        'TC' => 'Turks And Caicos Islands',
        'TV' => 'Tuvalu',
        'UG' => 'Uganda',
        'UA' => 'Ukraine',
        'AE' => 'United Arab Emirates',
        'GB' => 'United Kingdom',
        'US' => 'United States',
        'UM' => 'United States Outlying Islands',
        'UY' => 'Uruguay',
        'UZ' => 'Uzbekistan',
        'VU' => 'Vanuatu',
        'VE' => 'Venezuela',
        'VN' => 'Viet Nam',
        'VG' => 'Virgin Islands, British',
        'VI' => 'Virgin Islands, U.S.',
        'WF' => 'Wallis And Futuna',
        'EH' => 'Western Sahara',
        'YE' => 'Yemen',
        'ZM' => 'Zambia',
        'ZW' => 'Zimbabwe',
    );
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd do it:

```
// input string
$str = 'Hallands, Sweden';

// list the countries and their country codes
// i'd strtolower/strtoupper them all to make them case-insensitive, but i'll leave that up to you
$countries = array(
    // ...
    'Sweden' => 'SE'
    // ...
);

// separate $str at the comma
$parts = explode(',', $str);

// set the vars to false to later check if they were set correctly
$county = $parts[0]; // Hallands
$country = false;
$countrycode = false;

// check that you at least have two parts
if (count($parts) > 1) {
    $country = trim($parts[1]); // Sweden
    $countrycode = $country; // failsafe

    // check if the country is in the list
    if (array_key_exists($country, $countries)) {
        $countrycode = $countries[$country]; // SE
    }
}

// check if the vars are set correctly
if ($country != false && $countrycode != false) {
    // use them
    $str = $county.', '.$countrycode; // Hallands, SE
} else {
    // something went wrong
}
```